# Implicit declaration of memcmp is invalid in c99

Tags: c, xcode, c99

I'm creating a very basic C console application in Xcode 4 and I'm hitting a warning on compile: `Implicit declaration of memcmp is invalid in c99`.

My use of the function is as you would expect:

```
if(memcmp(buf, block, 0x14) != 0)
{
    fclose(fh);
    printf("invalid file: %s\n", argv[argc-1]);
    return 1;
}
```

How is the use of the function wrong and how can I go about fixing it?

Comment: It's actually undefined behavior in C89/C90 as well.  You should *always* `#include` the appropriate header for any library function you use.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <string.h>`, which contains the declaration of `memcmp`.